# Overlap of labels for MarkerWithLabel on custom marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I initially used an InfoBox to create a label for a marker with a custom icon. For the scenario of overlapping markers, the labels became illegible and so I had to look for a solution or alternative.

It was suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080536/how-to-solve-the-infobox-label-overlap-on-multiple-markers-on-google-map) that I should make use of MarkerWithLabel. It definitely helps, but if the markers overlap exactly, you can see the label still coming through even after setting the opacity to 1 and making the background the same as the custom marker.

[image]

```
.labels {
    background-color: #FF5959;
}

gmarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: someCenterPosition,
    icon: customImageURL,
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false,
    map: map,
    title: someTitle,
    labelContent: aTitle,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(someOffsetX, someOffsetY),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 1}
});
```

The 2 is actually the marker behind's label and 15 should be displayed on the front marker. I need to have the 2 and its background behind the marker with the label of 15.

Comment: See the fix in the related question: [Google maps Marker Label with multiple characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467212/google-maps-marker-label-with-multiple-characters) (append the label to the `markerLayer` rather than the `overlayImage`)

Comment: @geocodezip, I had a look and my version of markerwithlabel already includes that fix - so it does not fix this issue. For slightly overlapping markers, the labels react fine, but the issue arises when they overlap almost exactly.

Comment: @geocodezip, so it looks like manipulating the zIndex solves this issue if there is no other way.

Comment: @sim1 how did you solve this issue with zIndex. Can you explain where you changed the zIndex? I've tried changing it in many places to no avail. I am having the same overlapping issue when markers are close to each other. Thanks.